# PHP issue when using variable in if statement

Tags: php, variables

I can't find where I'm stuck maybe a problem with the use of integer or string I don't know.
Here is the code

```
$today = date("dmY");


if($row->$today == 0){

    if($update = $conn->query("UPDATE tablehmh SET `$today`= $poids WHERE email = '".$email."'")){

    }   
}
```

My problem comes from this part of the code

```
$row->$today
```

I'm very knew to php any help would be so much appreciated :)

Comment: You haven't defined `$row` anywhere. Where does this variable come from?

Comment: Why isn't it working? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: $row = $result->fetch_object()

row has multiple properties : id, email, 21062018, 22062018,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$today` doesn't look like it's part of a class/object. Yet, you are trying to access it as a property of an object.

If `$today` is part of an object, and that object is `$row` (as your code suggests)

```
if($row->$today == 0)
```

Then using `$row->$today` implies that you have an object property in `$row` that is named `210618`, which is an invalid property name.

Did you want to access the value of `$today`? If so, you don't want the `$` in front of $`today`.

```
if($row->today == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
This is my $row :
    $row = $result->fetch_object()

it has email property that I access easily:
    $row->email

And it also has a 21062018 property because my sql table is a sort of calendar with a date for each column name.
    if($row->21062018 == 0)
doesn't work too. Maybe I shouldn"t put numbers as column names ?

Comment: You should not use numbers as column names, especially if you plan to use the column names as a class property (because properties cannot start with a number).

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help I'll change that :)